# cannot connect intelliJ with Docker Machine

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I'm having troubles with connecting my docker compose with intelliJ. I am using Docker toolbox. I have the docker-compose.exe file downloaded and in the folder of Docker Toolbox. However, I cannot seem to get everything connected.

[image: When "connecting it gives a "Timeout Exceeded" error]

When I go to the "Docker"-tab of the settings, I get the following.

[image: Error in Docker-tab]

I am using the "Docker Machine" because on the Docker site it is said to use that.

Comment: Remove that Docker Machine path and leave it empty. Docker Machine and Docker Compose are totally different things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Through the highlighted *Docker Machine* path error, I guess you don't have *Docker Machine* installed.

You should then switch to **TCP Socket** connection to connect to *docker* daemon:

- IntelliJ IDEA:

  - Remove the *Docker Machine* path configured under *File | Settings | Build, Execution & Deployment | Docker | Tools*
  - Enable the **TCP Socket** under *File | Settings | Build, Execution & Deployment | Docker*
  - Set the *Engine API URL* to *tcp://localhost:2375* (should be the default if you didn't change it)
- Docker Desktop:

  - Expose the *docker* daemon, under *Settings | General*, enable *Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS* option
  - Restart *Docker Desktop* and you are good to go